# How do these emoji enablers manage to remain undetected while using WriteToFile outside sandbox?

Tags: iphone

Is there Hidden API that enables emoji?

Is there a hidden API that allows writing outside our app's sandbox secretly without detection?

HOW?! This is really baffling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that they use `NSUserDefaults`' `-persistentDomainForName:` and `-setPersistentDomain:forName:` to set a global user default (in `NSGlobalDomain`), though I'm not certain.